# NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 20: Unable to read image from file (). laravel 5.3

Tags: php, image, laravel, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload image in Laravel 5.3 but I am getting NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 20:

> Unable to read image from file ().
>
> error. Could anyone help me in it. I am using Image Intervention for
>   image upload.

**Below the code which i have tried :**

```
public function update(Request $request){

        // Handle the user upload of avatar
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();

        }

        return view('users/profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

    }
```

Comment: `$request->file('avatar')` returns an instance of `UploadedFile`.  Try `Image::make($avatar)->path()` instead.

Comment: Can you specify the size of file you're trying to upload?

Comment: no effect same error :(

Comment: Try to `dd($request->get('avatar'));` and see what its returning?

Comment: Size is 951 Kb .....

Comment: it returning NULL

Comment: It means you're not getting the file in request, check that if you're sending the file correctly!

Comment: I thnink everything is OK
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="POST">
                <label>Update Profile Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="avatar">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            </form>

Comment: Check the variables `post_max_size`, `file_uploads`, and `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini` file and make sure none of them are restricting what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's possible solution

```
 public function update(Request $request){

    // Handle the user upload of avatar
    if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar->path())->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();

    }

    return view('users/profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );

}
```

as Request's files are placed in temp directory you need to get path() of this file to pass it into Image::make

Comment: But now I am getting NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302: Image source not readable error

Comment: check weather your php installation has gd  extension enabled or imagick extension.  By default it uses gd extenstion.